# Real-time list of questions does not include SO in Japanese

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, realtime-questions

The [network-wide list of active questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime) on [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com) does not include any questions from [SO in Japanese](http://ja.stackoverflow.com). (I've been logging them for many hours, with not a single entry from that site, despite it being active.)

This appears to be a bug, because SO in Portuguese (and Russian) are represented there. The Japanese Language site is included too, so Japanese characters can't be the reason.

Comment: In the dropdown thingamajig the Japanese sits shows up if you search for "overflow," but not if you search for "stack overflow." The Portugese one and the regular one show up for both. ( cc @bluet )

Comment: Maybe because it's still without a category.

Comment: As long as they don't get spam, who cares if they appear in the real-time tab? ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Has a category now.